Can we pass tls certificate secrets in helm template dynamically?
I am using a manifest driven deployment strategy where I run helm template command that generates the desired manifest for the application deployment.
As part of my deployment I have route.yaml which contains tls fields like cacert, cert, key etc. I want to migrate these secrets from code repository to openshift from where I am expecting the route.yaml to dynamically fetch and add tls fields.
In my situation, since I am not performing helm deployment, rather using manifest driven deployment which is synced by ArgoCD.
Can I do something like this for my case?
  tls:
{{- if .Values.ingress.tlsSecretName }}
{{- $secretData := (lookup "v1" "Secret" .Release.Namespace .Values.ingress.tlsSecretName) }}
{{- if $secretData }}
{{- if hasKey $secretData.data "tls.crt" }}
    certificate: |
      {{- index $secretData.data "tls.crt" | b64dec | nindent 6 }}
{{- end }}
{{- if hasKey $secretData.data "tls.key" }}
    key: |
      {{- index $secretData.data "tls.key" | b64dec | nindent 6 }}
{{- end }}
{{- if hasKey $secretData.data "ca.crt" }}
    caCertificate: |
      {{- index $secretData.data "ca.crt" | b64dec | nindent 6 }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}

